# What happens when an object is left uninitialized during a copy constructor or in a assignment operator?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a vector object as one of the attributes and I do't initialize it in the copy constructor, what will happen then?
Also if I do this for any other object which does't have a default constructor, then what will happen?

Comment: It should be same , you don't have to explicit copy the items of vector into another, the default constructor - bit copy should do the work.

Comment: @dexterous_stranger If you bit-copy a `std::vector` you are in serious trouble.

Comment: If you define a copy constructor, the compiler doesn't generate one for you and doesn't attempt to override your code. So, if the `vector` is not copied, by you, in the copy constructor, it is not copied and the new object's `vector` will be empty

Comment: @TC - Default constructor is bitwise copy only. So, when you don't mention the copy constructor a default one will be called.

Comment: @dexterous_stranger No, it's not bitwise copy only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I have a vector object as one of the attributes and I do't initialize it in the copy constructor, what will happen then?

I suppose you are pertaining to initializing at the constructor initializer list. If that is so, the default constructor will be called, which you seem to have already answered here...

> Also if I do this for any other object which does't have a default constructor, then what will happen?

Your program will not run. More specifically, the compiler will shoot out an error, indicating that you're trying (or implicitly trying) to use that object's non-existing or inaccessible constructor. Try it to see for your self `;)`.

A way (read: not really *the* way) to get-around these types of objects is to have them dynamically allocated, that is, use `std::unique_ptr`s of them. In this way, you could delay their construction when the necessary arguments have been obtained. A better way though, if you can and you should, is to augment or wrap the class of the object to incorporate move semantics. With move semantics, you could eliminate that "delayed-construction-because-i-don't-yet-have-the-necessary-arguments" problem. The default constructor would leave the object's state uninitialized, i.e. unusable but re-initializable using a move/copy constructor. A great example for this is `std::thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy constructors are no different from other constructors. Class members that are not explicitly initialized inside a constructor are default-initialized, which means that members of class type are default constructed, each element of array members is default-initialized, and no initialization is  otherwise performed. If a class member doesn't have a default constructor and you don't initialize it in the copy constructor, the compiler will report an error.

(If you don't supply a copy constructor at all, the compiler will generate one for you that will copy-construct every non-static data member and base class subobject, if doing so is legal.)

As for assignment, class members not assigned to will simply retain their value before assignment.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) the relevant documentation. In particular,

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified. For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

So, if your custom-defined copy constructor doesn't end up copying a `vector` member, then your copy will be incorrect, since the `vector` will end up being default constructed. The C++ program will be entirely valid syntactically - the copy constructor will simply not be "correct". This applies in general to all default constructible members. If you have a member which isn't default constructible, then the code will simply not compile.